# CMAK Custom Action to run synchronous executable

Tags: vpn

I am using the Connection Manager Administration Kit (CMAK) to create vpn connections for my users, if it is possible how do I create a custom action that launches an executable that runs synchronously?

In the help file it says

> Only DLLs run synchronously, meaning
>   that Connection Manager starts the
>   action and then waits for the function
>   to return before continuing

Is there any way around this?

I have seen something similar called [VPN-Q](http://www.winfrasoft.com/vpnq.htm) which from the screen shots appear to do just that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Problem solved in another way